# Односторонняя маршрутизация между двумя посетями микротика

Tags: маршрутизация, mikrotik, маршрутизатор

Как сделать маршрутизацию между двумя посетями микротика?

Дано:

Микротик #1 - является Gateway для основной внутренней сети 10.1.1.0, DHCP сервером для 10.1.1.0

Микротик #2 - является WiFi точкой доступа для сети 10.1.1.0 на итерфейсе wlan1 / brige; локальные порты тоже включены в brige.
Микротик #2 - так же является DHCP сервером для подсети 10.0.0.0 на интерфейсе wlan2 / guest brige.

Вопрос:

Как настроить, чтобы из подсети 10.0.0.0 Микротик #2 выпускал пользоватеей в интернет через гейтвей 10.1.1.254 на Микротик #1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то у вас примерно так сделано
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для того чтобы обе подсети могли спокойно общаться между собой Mikrotik1 должен иметь маршрут к сети 10.0.0.0 (надо назначить статический адрес для Mikrotik2 и добавить статический маршрут в Mikrotik1 для гостевой сети), а в Mikrotik2 надо указать Mikrotik1 (10.1.1.254) в качестве шлюза по умолчанию. Как альтернатива можно поднять nat на интерфейсе bridge1 - тогда нет необходимости настраивать Mikrotik1, гости смогут попадать в инет и основную сеть, но из основной сети нельзя будет попасть в гостевую.

Comment: Да, у меня получилось все сделать, но несколько иным способом, я настроил chain srcnat на brige1, action: masqarade. А затем правилом firewall ограничил доступ в сеть 10.1.1.0 из сети 10.0.0.0. Все, работает, спасибо.